# Hadoop DFS is pointing to current directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

A few months ago, we installed CLoudera Hadoop 3 in our local machine and everything was fine. Recently we also installed Whirr to start working with clusters. Although we faced some problems, after a while, we can start up a cluster, log into its master node and commence work. However, I found out recently that when I type:

hadoop dfs -ls

into our local machine, it now displays everything in the current directory I am in, not the contents of the DFS. This didn't use to happen, so we are thinking something got messed up when we installed Whirr.

What could have caused this, and more importantly, how can we get our local hadoop dfs to point to the correct location?

Answer (score 1):

Is core-site.xml in the Hadoop installation conf directory set to `file:///`?